# How can I pass a Dictionary in MultipartFormData?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Controller that accepts both an `IFormFile` and an object (a class called `Document`) using form-data.

This is the Controller:

```c#
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormFile file, [FromForm] Document document, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    ...
}
```

This is what the `Document` class looks like:

```c#
public class Document
{
    public Guid DocumentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; } = DocumentType.Unsorted;
    public Dictionary<string, string> Metadata { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

And this is code that `POST`s data to said Controller:

```c#
using (var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    multipartContent.Add(new StringContent(document.DocumentId.ToString()), FormDataKeys.DocumentId);
    multipartContent.Add(new StringContent(document.DocumentType.ToString()), FormDataKeys.DocumentType);
    multipartContent.Add(new StreamContent(file), FormDataKeys.File, document.Name);

    using (var apiResult = await _httpClient.PostAsync("api/documents", multipartContent, token))
    {
        var content = await apiResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StoreDocumentResult>(content);
    }
}
```

This works, both the `IFormFile` and the properties of the `[FromForm] Document` parameter in the Controller are filled in when I send a POST request. Only, I'm clueless as to how I can fill the `Metadata` property of the `Document`? How can I pass a `Dictionary<string, string>` in `MultipartFormData`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to serialize the dictionary to string with JSON and than deserialize it.

```
     var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    settings.ContractResolver = new DictionaryAsArrayResolver();

    // serialize
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Document.Metadata, settings);
```

and than

```
   multipartContent.Add(new StringContent(json ), FormDataKeys.Metadata );
```

To deserialize it you can use something like this:

```
var d  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<String,String>>(json, settings);
```

Another option is to subclass the HttpContent and override the SerializeToStreamAsync method. In this case you can write into provided buffer whatever you want.

```
class DictionaryContent: HttpContent
{
   public Object Value { get; }

   public DictionaryContent( Object value)
   {
       Value = value;
       Headers.ContentType = .. You must provide the desired content type.
   }

   protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync( Stream stream, TransportContext context )
   {
        using ( var buffer = new BufferStreamWriter( stream, 4096 ) )
        {
            var writer = new JsonWriter( buffer, JsonSettings.Default );
            writer.WriteValue( Value ); // HERE You can do anything that you want.
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
}
```

Comment: For future reference: didn't find a way to actually bind to the `Metadata` property in `document`, so I've added an additional string parameter to the Controller that gets passed the serialized Dictionary as json. Then I deserialize that and assign it to the `Metadata` property.